# TensorFlow does not use all my VRAM though other apps do

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nvidia

I am using the tf.Keras for implementing my code and the TensorFlow only uses 5 out of my 6GB VRAM. Though other applications are fine I have seen video games take more than 5 GB of my VRam but TF is not. I have an RTX 2060, Tensorflow 2.1.0, CUDA 10.2 and python 3.6. I have tried different solutions but no luck so far, what I've tried:

1.

```
session_conf = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                                    inter_op_parallelism_threads=1,
                                    log_device_placement=True,
                                    allow_soft_placement=False)

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
K.set_session(sess)
```

2. 

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession
os.environ['TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH'] = 'true'

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 1
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
K.set_session(session)
```

3. 

```
os.environ['TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH'] = 'true'
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
tf.config.set_soft_device_placement(False)
tf.config.TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = True
```

what can I do?

Also, the GPU utilization shown by the task manager while running the code, is quite low at the first couple of seconds utilization is on 20% then it drops and stays at 1%.

EDIT:
I read [somewhere](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/15b9654e-5da7-45b7-93de-e8b63faef064/windows-10-does-not-let-cuda-applications-to-use-all-vram-on-especially-secondary-graphics-cards?forum=win10itprohardware) that it is a windows 10's problem, but if the games can use the memory why the TF can't?

Comment: It's not a windows 10 problem.  The usage of CUDA  on a GPU has various overheads associated with it.  One of these overheads is memory.  Just like your operating system uses some of the memory of your computer to do its work and housekeeping, so also CUDA uses some of the memory of your GPU to its work and housekeeping.  This overhead subtracts from the total amount of memory available to TF or any other compute application.  There are many factors that influence how much overhead there will be, including OS.  There is no practical way to get TF to use "all 6GB" of a 6GB GPU.

Comment: @Robert Crovella, thanks for the comment. Though I remember my previous laptop used to use 3.9/4 GB VRAM available with TF.